# Integrating World Pay Payment Gateway with PHP

Tags: php, payment-gateway, worldpay

Implementing worldpay payment gateway is driving me nuts. I am trying to implement worldpay payment gateway in a php website using XML direct method. I am using the code from [here](http://www.hurricanesoftwares.com/integrating-rbs-worldpay-xml-direct-method-in-ecommerce-with-php/) to handle all the HTTP requests.

But whenever I try to connect to their server I get error message that Authorization is required. I have supplied all the required details in the following url

$dest="https://$merchantCode:$password@secure-test.wp3.rbsworldpay.com/jsp/merchant/xml/paymentService.jsp";

Even when I use curl to connect to their server I get error message that url is not found.

Following is the curl code I am using.

```
    $ch = curl_init ($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$xml);   //$xml is the xml string
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 0);

    $result = curl_exec ($ch); // result will contain XML reply from WorldPay curl_close ($ch);
    if ( $result == false )
    {
    $error = "Curl could not retrieve page '$url', curl_exec returns false";               
    }
    echo $error;
    echo $result;
```

As there is no proper documentation, I request whoever has implemented it to please help me.

Currently I am testing the PHP website on my localhost. Is that the reason that the HTTP request or the curl is not working

Comment: Could it be a firewall issue or network settings issue on your local machine? What happens when you browse to that URL in a browser?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I open that link it asks for XML login details. But when I put merchant code and password, it doesn't do anything but asks for the login details again.

Comment: Here I have given the simple steps for WorldPay on your site. http://www.kvcodes.com/2016/08/worldpay-payment-gateway-integration-php/